# TypeError: The element or ID supplied is not valid. (videojs) Angular Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, video.js

I am trying to control a video player via videojs with in my ionic app. The code I have inside of my controller is:

```
        $scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded', function() {
            console.log('view loaded!!!');
            if ($scope.post.media.length > 0) {
                var myPlayer = null;
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.post.media.length; i++) {
                    videojs("bc-video-0").ready(function () {
                        myPlayer = this;
                    });

                    myPlayer.on('loadstart', function () {
                        console.log('well something happened');
                    })
                }
            }
        });
```

where I use the life cycle event $ionicView.loaded to wait for all of the template code to be loaded onto the page. Then in my template file I have:

```
            <div ng-repeat = "video in post.media | limitTo:videoLimit" class="video-box">
                <!--limitTo:videoLimit |-->
                <h3 class="video-title">{{video.title}}</h3>
                <p ng-bind-html = "video.info"></p>
                <!-- BRIGHTCOVE -->
                <div style="display: block; position: relative; width: 100%;" >
                    <div style="display: block; position: relative; width: 100%;">
                        <div style="display: block; padding-top: 56.25%;" data-tap-disable="true">
                            <video
                                    id="{{'bc-video-' + $index}}"
                                    style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; left: 0px;"
                                    data-video-id=" {{video.file}}"
                                    data-account="XXXXXXXXXX"
                                    data-player="XXXXXXXXXX"
                                    data-embed="default"
                                    class="video-js"
                                    controls="">
                                <source ng-src = "{{video.src | trusted}}">
                            </video>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p style="display: none;">source: {{video.src}}</p>
            </div>
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: The element or ID supplied is not valid. (videojs)
```

When I inspect I see that the first video id is indeed bc-video-0, any idea on what I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

Try enclosing your script inside the $timeout(). had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing player in ngAfterViewInit solved the issue for me

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.player = this.initPlayer(this.config, this.pid);
}
```